# how to sort data you are fetching from the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, date

I am getting some data from api.I have to sort date.let me give example in an array where is 10 dictionary in that i have parameter called start time.I have to show lates event first flowed next coming event like today event first and tomorrow event next.

I gone through lot of example I cant understand  that can some one help me.

this the result coming from api .

```
(
        {
        bookingTime = "<null>";
        clubAddress = "Grand by GRT Hotels, Lobby Level, Sir Thyagaraya Road, Thyagaraya Nagar , Chennai";
        clubCity = "Chennai,India";
        clubFacilities = "<null>";
        clubInfoID = 270;
        clubLatitude = "13.0402612";
        clubLoc = Chennai;
        clubLongitude = "80.2423";
        clubMobileNumber = "<null>";
        clubName = "The Code-Grand by GRT Hotels";
        clubType = "Night club";
        clubberMobile = "<null>";
        clubberName = "<null>";
        count = 0;
        coupleCover = 0;
        coupleEntry = 0;
        couplePayment = "<null>";
        description = "<null>";
        distance = 0;
        djId = "<null>";
        dressCode = "<null>";
        endDate = "2017-07-03 18:00:00";
        entryCancellationTime = "<null>";
        eventOffer = "<null>";
        eventType = DANCE;
        favoriteType = NO;
        festivalList = "<null>";
        "idclub_event" = 6042;
        moodDJ = "<null>";
        moodMusic = "Salsa, Bachata, Kizomba";
        moodTheme = "LATIN CODE NIGHT";
        offerCredits = 0;
        paidStatus = NOTPAID;
        personAllowed = 0;
        pictureType = IMAGE;
        rateAmbience = 0;
        rateAvg = 0;
        rateFood = 0;
        rateMusic = 0;
        rateService = 0;
        rsvpEntryTime = "<null>";
        rsvpRequestTime = "<null>";
        rsvpStatus = NO;
        rsvpType = BOTH;
        stagCover = 0;
        stagEntry = 0;
        stagPayment = "<null>";
        startDate = "2017-07-03 15:30:00";
        stopEdit = "<null>";
    },
        {
        bookingTime = "<null>";
        clubAddress = "309 Rajiv Gandhi Salai (OMR), Sholinganallur, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600119";
        clubCity = "Chennai,India";
        clubFacilities = "<null>";
        clubInfoID = 276;
        clubLatitude = "12.9056392";
        clubLoc = Sholinganallur;
        clubLongitude = "80.2256728";
        clubMobileNumber = "<null>";
        clubName = "The Gateway Hotel";
        clubType = Pub;
        clubberMobile = "<null>";
        clubberName = "<null>";
        count = 0;
        coupleCover = 0;
        coupleEntry = 0;
        couplePayment = "<null>";
        description = "<null>";
        distance = 0;
        djId = "<null>";
        dressCode = "<null>";
        endDate = "2017-09-23 16:00:00";
        entryCancellationTime = "<null>";
        eventOffer = "<null>";
        eventType = DANCE;
        favoriteType = NO;
        festivalList = "<null>";
        "idclub_event" = 5945;
        moodDJ = "<null>";
        moodMusic = "Bachata ";
        moodTheme = "Toke D Keda: Bachata Concert";
        offerCredits = 0;
        paidStatus = NOTPAID;
        personAllowed = 0;
        pictureType = IMAGE;
        rateAmbience = 0;
        rateAvg = 0;
        rateFood = 0;
        rateMusic = 0;
        rateService = 0;
        rsvpEntryTime = "<null>";
        rsvpRequestTime = "<null>";
        rsvpStatus = NO;
        rsvpType = BOTH;
        stagCover = 0;
        stagEntry = 0;
        stagPayment = "<null>";
        startDate = "2017-09-23 10:00:00";
        stopEdit = "<null>";
    },
```

please help me to sort this,thaks for quick responce.

Comment: Can you provide the class 
that will help to write the answer , 
plus if you provide more than 2 object in the list that is will be better

Comment: Thanks for quick responce ,I havent written any code for that sorting the date but for distance sorting i have code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse api response and store the event details in a model class. Finally you will get Array of `Events`

Then sort the array by using `NSSortDescriptor`

```
//startDate key is the variable name of your `Event` model. Where you stored the event dates
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];

// ascending YES/NO based on your needs

NSArray *sortedEventsList = [arrayOfEvents sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

**Sort dictionary by date**

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 

NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
for (int i=0; i<list.count; i++) { 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [list[i] mutableCopy]; 
NSString *datestr=dict[@"startDate"]; 
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:datestr]; 

dict[@"startDate"] = date; 
dateArray[i] = dict; 
} 
NSLog(@"%@",dateArray); 
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:YES];
```

Comment: only this two lines enough for sorting

Comment: Yes, It will give you the sorted array.

Comment: Do you have array of custom objects?

Comment: -(NSMutableArray *)sortdanzabydate:(NSArray *)list type:(NSString *)type
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    
    // ascending YES/NO based on your needs
    
    NSArray *sortedEventsList = [list sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    NSLog(@"%@",sortedEventsList);

Comment: You have to construct the array of  events object and perform this on operation that array.

Comment: can you pls give me full answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148243/discussion-between-subramanian-and-satheeshkumar-naidu).

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu  As per our discussion, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I create a class

```
public class MyOwnModel
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Header { get; set; }
            public string Body { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
        }
```

and I am getting my Data as a json

```
    [{"ID":1,"Header":"First Notifications","Body":"Body of alert","Active":true}
,{"ID":2,"Header":"Second Notifications","Body":"Body 2","Active":true}
,{"ID":3,"Header":"Third Notifications","Body":"Body 3","Active":true}
,{"ID":4,"Header":"Fourth Notification","Body":"Body 4","Active":true}]
```

[image: before sorting]

and here after the sorting you see the first item with ID 4 
[image: After Sorting]

How I did it 
I just used `System.Linq;`

```
var objSorted = from a in obj orderby a.ID descending select a;
```

you can replace id with Date and since you want to sort today then tomorrow 
this should be ascending 
when you get the data you make sure you getting data of Today and up not yesterday then the sort will be correct ascending 
Good luck

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the Tag , sure here is the answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it 
change the birthdat to Date

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                           ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];